# call arbitrary functions as First Class Functions in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-variant

My intention was to use arbitrary functions as First Class Variables. I used the visitor pattern (at least i think that's what that is) to achieve effectively arbitrary functions as First Class Variables.

Is there a better way to achieve this?
Except for safety, is there a big drawback in this design?

Here is a minimal working example, using boost 1.76.0 and C++20 standard:

```
    boost::variant<void*,int> rep (){
        return 2;
    }
    
    boost::variant<void*,int> oll(){
        std::cout << "happiness" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    boost::variant<void*,int> iuu(int a ){
        return  a;
    }


    class my_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<boost::variant<void*,int>>
    {
    public:
        boost::variant<void*,int> operator()(boost::variant<void*,int>(*fun)() ) const
        {
            return fun();
        }

        boost::variant<void*,int> operator()(boost::variant<void*,int>(*fun)(int) ) const
        {
    
            return fun(argument);
        }
        int argument;
    };


    int main() {
        boost::variant<boost::variant<void*,int>(*)(), boost::variant<void*,int>(*)(int)> varob(iuu);
        my_visitor vis = my_visitor();
        vis.argument = 22;
        std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(vis, varob);
```

Comment: I dont know what a "First Class Function" is. Could you explain?

Comment: actually I did read the wikipedia article, which states "This means the language supports passing functions as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures" but thats already doable with function pointers, so I don't understand whats your aim

Comment: Why use `boost::variant` rather than `std::variant` that is in C++17 and later?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? How do you plan to use this arrangement? What problem do you believe it will help you solve? It's not clear to me what "*this*" in "better way to achieve *this*" stands for.

Comment: I think the structure i implemented is called dynamic dispatch. The problem with function pointers is that they cannot be used in a datastructure whilst supporting any arbitrary function signature (is that statement true?). Changing the pointers to void* could achieve that but loses the information needed to cast back  in the process(is that statement true?). And i think in most implementations won't allow casting to void* anyway - and it's bad practice anyhow.